# Repeating 503's messages when querying DBpedia

Tags: dbpedia, http-status-code-503

I'm conducting a series of queries to DBpedia SPARQL endpoint (from inside a loop). The code looks more or less like this:

```java
for (String citySplit : citiesSplit) {
  RepositoryConnection conn = dbpediaEndpoint.getConnection();
  String sparqlQueryLat = " SELECT ?lat ?lon WHERE { "
                        + "<http://dbpedia.org/resource/" + citySplit.trim().replaceAll(" ", "_") + "> <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#lat> ?lat . "
                        + "<http://dbpedia.org/resource/" + citySplit.trim().replaceAll(" ", "_") + "> <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#long> ?lon ."
                        + "}";
  TupleQuery queryLat = conn.prepareTupleQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, sparqlQueryLat);
  TupleQueryResult resultLat = queryLat.evaluate();
}
```

The problem is that, after a few iterations, I get a 503 message:

```
httpclient.wire.header - << "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable[\r][\n]"
(...)
org.openrdf.query.QueryInterruptedException
    at org.openrdf.http.client.HTTPClient.getTupleQueryResult(HTTPClient.java:1041)
    at org.openrdf.http.client.HTTPClient.sendTupleQuery(HTTPClient.java:438)
    at org.openrdf.http.client.HTTPClient.sendTupleQuery(HTTPClient.java:413)
    at org.openrdf.repository.http.HTTPTupleQuery.evaluate(HTTPTupleQuery.java:41)
```

If I understand correctly, this 503 message is from DBpedia. Am I right? 
The number of consecutive queries that manage to succeed is variable. Sometimes it runs for 13 seconds before getting the message, sometimes 15 minutes. 
In any case, I don't think this is normal.
What could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

The [Accessing the DBpedia Data Set over the Web](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/OnlineAccess#h28-3) page of the DBpedia wiki says, in section [1.1. Public SPARQL Endpoint](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/OnlineAccess#h28-3) says:

> Fair Use Policy: Please read [this post](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-lod/2011Aug/0028.html) for information about restrictions on the public DBpedia endpoint. These might also be usefull [sic]: [1](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=30412765), [2](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=29172307).

The linked post says that the public DBpedia SPARQL endpoint implements rate limiting.

> The http://dbpedia.org/sparql endpoint has both rate limiting on the  number of connections/sec you can make, as well as restrictions on  resultset and query time, as per the following settings:
>
> ```
> [SPARQL]
> ResultSetMaxRows           = 2000
> MaxQueryExecutionTime      = 120
> MaxQueryCostEstimationTime = 1500
> ```
>
> These are in place to make sure that everyone has a equal chance to de-reference data from dbpedia.org, as well as to guard against badly  written queries/robots.

I think that it is likely that you are hitting that limit.