# How to lookup predicates from a subject URINode

Tags: c#, dotnetrdf, rdf-xml

I don't realy understand how to read te predicates (URINodes) from a subject URINode.

Also, is there anyway to lookup IURINodes by specific predicates values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found my required methode on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967686/retrieving-specific-rdf-graph-triples-based-on-predicate-nodes)!

**My solution:**

```
//Path to RDF/XML file
pathToRDF = "c:\dotNetRdfExample\exampleRDF.xml"

// A IGraph Parser, implementing the IRdfReader interface (So it can work with RDF/XML formats)
RdfXmlParser rxpparser = new RdfXmlParser();

// Create a graph for the rdf data
Graph g = new Graph();

// Makes sure that the XML file is UTF8
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathToRDF, true);

// Fill the empty IGraph, using the rdfXmlParser
rxpparser.Load(g, sr);

// Retrieve all triples with the specified predicate and object
IEnumerable<Triple> specificTriples = g.GetTriplesWithPredicateObject(g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type")), 
        g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("http://www.projectenportfolio.nl/wiki/index.php/Speciaal:URIResolver/Category-3AHandelingsperspectief")));
```